# web3 getStorageAt does not return expected mapping value

Tags: web3js, get-storage-at

Beginner here, I dont manage to get the value of a mapping key.

Network is Fantom.

Contract Adress is 0xce761D788DF608BD21bdd59d6f4B54b2e27F25Bb.

mapping variable is adventures_log

Key is 1125349.

I use this code:

```
var key = web3.utils.padLeft(web3.utils.toHex(1125349).toString().replace("0x", ""), 64)

let slot = "0".repeat(64)

let newKey = web3.utils.sha3(key+slot, { "encoding": 'hex' })

let result = await web3.eth.getStorageAt(

'0xce761D788DF608BD21bdd59d6f4B54b2e27F25Bb',  

newKey,

    )

console.log(result);
```

On ftmscan the mapping returns the correct value. But my code always returns 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

I already tried it with different slot numbers up to 9. But always 0x0 is returned.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any solution for this ? I experience the same thing..

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not solve that issue, and refrained from using getStoragetAt.